# R Shiny: `numericInput` number with tsd separators `onExit` and without when `onFocus`

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, how can I custom format `numericInput` control so that when user clicks outside the control (on-exit event), the number in the control (which he has just entered) is displayed with thousand separators ? When the user clicks back inside the control (on-focus event), separators should disappear and reappear on each exit event.

Pseudocode:

```
value = 1000000 # this has been previously entered inside the numericInput and cached

if(onFocus)
    prettyNum(value, big.mark = "", scientific=FALSE)
else if(onExit)
    prettyNum(value, big.mark = ",", scientific=FALSE)
```

Comment: The short answer, I would imagine, is that you can't do this strictly with `Shiny`, but if you're willing to use jquery, you could use `$("#input_id").focus(function() {...} )` where `{...}` might be something like `parseInt(number).toLocaleString()`. Again, this only works if you're willing to use javascript/jquery.

Comment: I'm still surprised by the inflexible ``inputs`` in shiny... Should be easy to make them a bit more appealing.